# Report_Builder incompatible character encodings: UTF-8 and ASCII-8BIT (Encoding::CompatibilityError)

Tags: ruby, selenium, cucumber, capybara

I'm using the report_builder gem for ruby but, almost always that I run a regression with a lot of scenarios, the report don't is builded and this error:

```
`Traceback (most recent call last):
    31: from C:/meuvivo-site-automation/features/support/hooks.rb:150:in `block in <top (required)>'
    30: from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/report_builder-1.9/lib/report_builder.rb:76:in `build_report'
    29: from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/report_builder-1.9/lib/report_builder/builder.rb:44:in `build_report'
    28: from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/report_builder-1.9/lib/report_builder/builder.rb:44:in `open'
    27: from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/report_builder-1.9/lib/report_builder/builder.rb:45:in `block in build_report'
    26: from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/2.5.0/erb.rb:877:in `result'
    25: from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/2.5.0/erb.rb:877:in `eval'
    24: from (erb):12:in `block in build_report'
    23: from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/2.5.0/erb.rb:877:in `result'
    22: from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/2.5.0/erb.rb:877:in `eval'
    21: from (erb):1:in `block in build_report'
    20: from (erb):1:in `each_with_index'
    19: from (erb):1:in `each'
    18: from (erb):2:in `block (2 levels) in build_report'
    17: from (erb):2:in `each_with_index'
    16: from (erb):2:in `each'
    15: from (erb):4:in `block (3 levels) in build_report'
    14: from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/2.5.0/erb.rb:877:in `result'
    13: from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/2.5.0/erb.rb:877:in `eval'
    12: from (erb):20:in `block (3 levels) in build_report'
    11: from (erb):20:in `each'
    10: from (erb):21:in `block (4 levels) in build_report'
     9: from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/2.5.0/erb.rb:877:in `result'
     8: from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/2.5.0/erb.rb:877:in `eval'
     7: from (erb):28:in `block (4 levels) in build_report'
     6: from (erb):28:in `each'
     5: from (erb):29:in `block (5 levels) in build_report'
     4: from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/2.5.0/erb.rb:877:in `result'
     3: from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/2.5.0/erb.rb:877:in `eval'
     2: from (erb):15:in `block (5 levels) in build_report'
     1: from (erb):15:in `each'
```

`block (6 levels) in build_report': incompatible character encodings: UTF-8 and ASCII-8BIT (Encoding::CompatibilityError)`

Someone already have this problem and knows how resolve?

Answer (score 0):

Soluction that I've found is:
1° Put #encoding: utf-8  on top of all features

2° On function take_screenshot, use attach("data:image/png;base64,#{page.driver.browser.screenshot_as(:base64)}", 'image/png')

to add screenschot in html report
PS: Depending on your ruby version, will be necessary change attach for embed
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oVNiU.png)